# Spark sql pivot

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I have this [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d4bycNUH-DYQNbwFJdKEz4cG6ATanpyI/view?usp=sharing) where I am trying to do a pivot using spark sql. The end result needs to be this way .

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|Product           |AVG_CENTRAL       |AVG_EAST          |AVG_WEST          |avg(Autonumber)   |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|Air Purifiers     |300.3333333333333 |449.875           |348.5             |399.7692307692308 |
|Art Supplies      |352.42857142857144|349.48837209302326|324.94444444444446|344.14666666666665|
|Baby Food         |372.0             |null              |null              |372.0             |
|Beverages         |320.0             |409.0             |null              |379.3333333333333 |
|Binder Clips      |70.5              |551.8571428571429 |494.0             |453.8181818181818 |
|Binding Machines  |null              |null              |361.0             |361.0             |
|Binding Supplies  |610.0             |462.2             |616.0             |529.8888888888889 |
|Biscuits          |505.0             |469.5             |null              |481.3333333333333 |
|Bread             |null              |266.0             |328.0             |297.0             |
|Business Envelopes|421.0             |356.25            |null              |369.2             |
|Cakes             |null              |314.0             |null              |314.0             |
|Cardboard Storage |409.0             |null              |null              |409.0             |
|Cereals           |583.0             |356.38461538461536|278.6666666666667 |356.0             |
|Clocks            |null              |220.2             |445.5             |284.57142857142856|
|Colored Envelopes |615.0             |524.0             |222.0             |471.25            |
|Computer Paper    |358.84615384615387|370.02564102564105|377.6666666666667 |369.9142857142857 |
|Copy Paper        |300.2857142857143 |454.8888888888889 |223.55555555555554|361.8235294117647 |
|End Tables        |null              |36.0              |234.0             |135.0             |
|File Labels       |351.8333333333333 |325.52941176470586|379.0             |344.4193548387097 |
|Frames            |471.0             |258.5             |709.0             |325.84615384615387|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I tried the following query for pivot.

```
spark.sql("""SELECT *  FROM (SELECT Product,Region,Autonumber FROM Test) TEST PIVOT (avg(Autonumber) FOR Region in ('Central' AVG_CENTRAL, 'East' AVG_EAST, 'West' AVG_WEST  )) ORDER BY PRODUCT""")
```

The resulting dataframe was this ->

```
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|           Product|       AVG_CENTRAL|          AVG_EAST|          AVG_WEST|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|     Air Purifiers| 300.3333333333333|           449.875|             348.5|
|      Art Supplies|352.42857142857144|349.48837209302326|324.94444444444446|
|         Baby Food|             372.0|              null|              null|
|         Beverages|             320.0|             409.0|              null|
|      Binder Clips|              70.5| 551.8571428571429|             494.0|
|  Binding Machines|              null|              null|             361.0|
|  Binding Supplies|             610.0|             462.2|             616.0|
|          Biscuits|             505.0|             469.5|              null|
|             Bread|              null|             266.0|             328.0|
|Business Envelopes|             421.0|            356.25|              null|
|             Cakes|              null|             314.0|              null|
| Cardboard Storage|             409.0|              null|              null|
|           Cereals|             583.0|356.38461538461536| 278.6666666666667|
|            Clocks|              null|             220.2|             445.5|
| Colored Envelopes|             615.0|             524.0|             222.0|
|    Computer Paper|358.84615384615387|370.02564102564105| 377.6666666666667|
|        Copy Paper| 300.2857142857143| 454.8888888888889|223.55555555555554|
|        End Tables|              null|              36.0|             234.0|
|       File Labels| 351.8333333333333|325.52941176470586|             379.0|
|            Frames|             471.0|             258.5|             709.0|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I wanted to get the avg of the Autonumber column for each product which I did after these steps.

```
spark.sql("""SELECT PRODUCT , AVG(Autonumber) from test group by product""").show

+--------------------+------------------+
|             PRODUCT|   avg(Autonumber)|
+--------------------+------------------+
|Fruits and Vegeta...|401.09541984732823|
|              Clocks|284.57142857142856|
|         File Labels| 344.4193548387097|
|        Art Supplies|344.14666666666665|
| Specialty Envelopes|             247.0|
|          Copy Paper| 361.8235294117647|
|      Computer Paper| 369.9142857142857|
|        Highlighters|              17.5|
|     Standard Labels|400.42857142857144|
|    Portable Storage|             295.4|
|             Pencils|419.14285714285717|
|  Round Ring Binders|292.93333333333334|
|                Meat| 365.1111111111111|
|       Writings Pads| 336.5833333333333|
|             Cereals|             356.0|
|          End Tables|             135.0|
|    Storage Cabinets|             267.5|
|              Frames|325.84615384615387|
|       Office Chairs|             376.0|
|       Air Purifiers| 399.7692307692308|
+--------------------+------------------+

scala> df1.join(df2 , "product").show(false)
```

Only then I could acheive my final result . 
Is there any way I can acheive this in the pivot query itself ?
Any help would be great.
Also its really difficult to find blog posts on the sql syntax of pivot in spark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way of doing this. I went through [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-multi-dimensional-aggregation.html) article and found that rollup and cube can be used to resolve this

Code:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM (select region , product , avg(autonumber) as autonumber from test group by cube (region , product) order by product NULLS LAST , region nulls last) pivot (avg(autonumber) for region in ('Central' Central , 'East' East , 'West' West , null Total)) order by product nulls last").show()
```

Output

```
+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|             product|           Central|              East|              West|             Total|
+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|       Air Purifiers| 300.3333333333333|           449.875|             348.5| 399.7692307692308|
|        Art Supplies|352.42857142857144|349.48837209302326|324.94444444444446|344.14666666666665|
|           Baby Food|             372.0|              null|              null|             372.0|
|           Beverages|             320.0|             409.0|              null| 379.3333333333333|
|        Binder Clips|              70.5| 551.8571428571429|             494.0| 453.8181818181818|
|    Binding Machines|              null|              null|             361.0|             361.0|
|    Binding Supplies|             610.0|             462.2|             616.0| 529.8888888888889|
|            Biscuits|             505.0|             469.5|              null| 481.3333333333333|
|               Bread|              null|             266.0|             328.0|             297.0|
|  Business Envelopes|             421.0|            356.25|              null|             369.2|
|               Cakes|              null|             314.0|              null|             314.0|
|   Cardboard Storage|             409.0|              null|              null|             409.0|
|             Cereals|             583.0|356.38461538461536| 278.6666666666667|             356.0|
|              Clocks|              null|             220.2|             445.5|284.57142857142856|
|   Colored Envelopes|             615.0|             524.0|             222.0|            471.25|
|      Computer Paper|358.84615384615387|370.02564102564105| 377.6666666666667| 369.9142857142857|
|          Copy Paper| 300.2857142857143| 454.8888888888889|223.55555555555554| 361.8235294117647|
|          End Tables|              null|              36.0|             234.0|             135.0|
|         File Labels| 351.8333333333333|325.52941176470586|             379.0| 344.4193548387097|
|              Frames|             471.0|             258.5|             709.0|325.84615384615387|
|Fruits and Vegeta...|             493.4|           366.408| 385.4805194805195|401.09541984732823|
|  Heavy Duty Binders| 489.6666666666667| 423.6666666666667|             556.0|             481.5|
|        Highlighters|              null|              null|              17.5|              17.5|
|            Lighting|              null|              null|             141.0|             141.0|
|                Meat|             469.5|          343.4375| 324.4166666666667| 365.1111111111111|
| Meeting Room Tables|             449.0|             447.0|             401.5|434.57142857142856|
|     Metal Bookcases|              null| 571.6666666666666|              null| 571.6666666666666|
|       Office Chairs|             534.4|             193.5|             360.5|             376.0|
|         Paper Clips|             459.0|392.77777777777777|             466.0|          423.9375|
|             Pencils|             508.0|             441.5|              19.0|419.14285714285717|
|      Pins and Tacks|              null|             426.5|232.33333333333334|             310.0|
|    Portable Storage|             535.0|             251.0|             291.0|             295.4|
|  Round Ring Binders| 271.2857142857143| 404.3333333333333|              34.5|292.93333333333334|
|        Rubber Bands|              null|             412.0|              null|             412.0|
|            Scissors|              null|             374.0|             346.6|354.42857142857144|
| Specialty Envelopes|             448.0|               8.0|              84.0|             247.0|
|              Spices| 508.3333333333333|             326.0|              null|            462.75|
|     Standard Labels|             429.0| 360.7857142857143|451.14285714285717|400.42857142857144|
|    Storage Cabinets|              45.0|              null| 341.6666666666667|             267.5|
|    Surge Protectors|             465.0|             366.0|             348.5|             382.0|
|       Writings Pads|             289.5| 384.6666666666667|             286.5| 336.5833333333333|
|                null| 427.3090909090909|368.02349869451695|357.15458937198065|             378.0|
+--------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `LEFT JOIN` to achieve the results.
Your final column could be fetched using -

```
    df = spark.sql(""" 
    SELECT 
        A.*, B.avg_autoNumber
    FROM 
        (SELECT Product, AVG_CENTRAL, AVG_WEST, AVG_EAST FROM Test) A
        LEFT JOIN (Select Product, avg(ALL) as avg(Autonumber) avg_autoNumber) B
    ON A.Product = B.Product
    """)
    df.show()
```

Comment: Join causes an extra shuffle